# Building Tesseract in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, tesseract

When I try to build the Tesseract solution in Visual C++ 2010 Express it's saying:

```
21>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: The command "post-build.cmd "C:\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract-3.01\vs2010\Release\" "C:\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract-3.01\vs2010\bin.rel"
21>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 4.
========== Build: 20 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I don't know how to proceed. Does anyone know what the problem is and how I can solve it?

Comment: Check [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/f4d512a3-3f95-4a78-8e43-cb19ceca6cfe/) out.

Comment: Nothing to do with [tag:opencv] so I removed the tag.

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit post-build.cmd file in [tesseract source]\vs2010 folder as follows
Open the file, in Notepad++ for example, and "rem" the following lines:

```
xcopy ..\vs2008\lib\liblept168%DebugVersion%.dll %TargetFolder% /Y /I /D
rem copy data
if not exist %DataFolder% (
   md %DataFolder%
)
xcopy ..\TessData\eng.traineddata %DataFolder% /Y /I /D
```

This should do it, if you have installed the executables previously. Since `tesseract` gets the `\tessdata\` folder from environmental variable (`TESSDATA_PREFIX`) in "mainblk.cpp" file  in `main_setup` function there is no need to copy data folder as instructed in post-build.cmd.

If you didn't install the executables then you have to create this variable manually. the value should indicate the folder where \tessdata\ resides no the \tessdata\ itself since in the last line of main_setup `\tessdata` is added to the path.

Answer (score 0):

run vs2010 as administrator and build again as raym0nd has suggested. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't install [tesseract-ocr-3.01.eng.tar.gz](http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-ocr-3.01.eng.tar.gz) properly.

From their [readme](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ReadMe):

> Download these packages:
>
> tesseract-3.01.tar.gz - tesseract source
>
> tesseract-3.01-win_vs.zip - Visual studio (2008 & 2010) solution with
>   necessary libraries
>
> tesseract-ocr-3.01.eng.tar.gz - English language file for tesseract
>   (or download other 3.01 or 3.00 language datafile)
>
> Unpack them to one directory ('tesseract-3.01').
>   tesseract-ocr-3.01.eng.tar.gz has wrong name of root directory
>   ('tesseract-ocr' instead of 'tesseract-3.01'). Windows relevant files
>   are located in vs2008 directory (e.g. 'tesseract-3.01\vs2008'). The
>   same build process as usual applies: Open tesseract.sln with
>   VC++Express 2008 and build all (or just Tesseract) It should compile
>   (in at least release mode) without having to install anything further.
>   The dll dependencies and Leptonica are included. Output will be in
>   tesseract-3.01\vs2008\bin (or tesseract-3.01\vs2008\bin.rd or
>   tesseract-3.01\vs2008\bin.dbg based on configuration build).